# How do I distribute cells in a grid with the new UI from script?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, grid

I'm trying to fill a grid with buttons (using UnityUI), but I want them to fill the entire screen, so I calculate it's size on the fly.

I have an empty GameObject, child of the main Canvas, with a GridLayoutGroup component, and attached to it my script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Collections;

 public class CrearTablero: MonoBehaviour {

   public int rows = 4;
   public int columns = 4;

   private int buttonWidth;
   private int buttonHeight;

   public Button prefab;
   private Button button;

   void Start () {

     buttonHeight = Screen.height / rows;
     buttonWidth = Screen.width / columns;

     GridLayoutGroup grid = this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup> ();

     grid.cellSize = new Vector2 (buttonWidth,buttonHeight);

     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
             button = (Button)Instantiate(prefab);
             button.transform.SetParent(transform);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

With this I've tried to make the buttons childs of the Empty GameObject and, since they are childs of a GridLayoutGroup I expected them to appear arranged properly, but when I try it, this is what I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?